# Which is the best place to keep logic in angular?

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular application. Let's say when we are implementing a feature like onclick of some button, call an api, process the data, show results in table. Table data should be retained across pages(so we need to keep the variable in service).

For implementation, first we can start calling function from template, then in component we can do some checks, and call a service to fetch data. Once we get the data, if we want to process the data, in that case function to process the data should be in component or service ??

Can we write logic in service file? Or it should be in component file? What is the best practise?

Approach 1:

```
 getApi() {
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .subscribe(response=> {
          this.afterFetchingProcessData(response); // this might be some function in service file
      },error=>{
          // handle error
      });
  }

  afterFetchingProcessData(response){
       //process the data and assign to variable 
       this.tabledata = response;
  }
```

Or we should follow the below pattern

Approach 2: 
In component file:

```
 getApi() {
      this.service.getApi().subscribe(response=> {
          this.afterFetchingProcessData(response); // this might be some function in service file
      },error=>{
          // handle error
      });
  }

  afterFetchingProcessData(response){
       //process the data and assign to variable 
       this.service.tabledata = response;
  }
```

In service file just call Api and return the response

```
 getApi() {
    return this.http
      .get(url);
  }
```

Which is best practice to follow Approach 1 or Approach 2 and why?

Comment: You should apply main logic in your `component` file, `service` file should only be used to make an `api` call preferably.

Comment: Any reason behind this? Lets say we are getting error from api , we need to show error message on ui..  Where we need to keep this logic? If we are writing in service we can reuse the error func for all api calls

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Answer (score 6):

Approach 2 is the better choice IMO.

The way I see it -

- **Components** - comprise the presentation layer, and should focus on presenting to the user and acquiring inputs from him
- **Services** - do all other things

And I would go a step further to separate the Services into:

- **Side Effects Services** - in charge of e.g. API calls
- **Main Services** - encapsulating the *behavior* of the app

Answer (score 3):

For anything but prototypes and simple or shortlived applications, anything but the simplest business logic should be extracted to class-based services or other dependencies. At the very least, components should be divided into presentational components and container components or a similar pattern.

I will quote my own article "[Lean Angular components](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/lean-angular-components-1abl)".

> Lean Angular components in a nutshell
> For simple applications or projects with a short lifespan, mixed components are acceptable since there’s not a big need for maintainability, scalability or even testability of the codebase.
>
> For large, complex applications, we have a higher need for maximising the valuable traits that were just mentioned. To do this, we need presentational components that only contain logic that belongs to the presentational, horizontal application layers. These components should only deal with a concern at a single abstraction level.
>
> Lean presentational components are only concerned about presenting information to our users and allow them to interact with the application. Implementation details are left for other software artifacts that belong in different horizontal application layers. Complex logic for presentation or user interaction is delegated to component level services such as presenters.
>
> We can also have lean container components. They project application state to presentational components and convert application-specific events to commands that affect the application state. Complex logic is delegated to a component level service such as a facade—maybe even a component-specific service.

As discussed in this article, making the component model lean and thin corresponds to several advices in the Angular style guide.

Where should shared state live then? Here are some options:

- Class-based services with RxJS subjects
- A page/container component high in the component tree
- A state container or other options in state management frameworks/libaries such as RxAngular State, Elf, NgRx Store, NgRx Effects, NgRx Component Store, Akita, NGXS, Redux-Observable, MobX, or NGXF

Comment: your link is broken, can you update it to the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

Follow no2 cause its Well Structured
Simple Way: call method in Html -> In ts Declare that method -> For Api call create a service where you can call the all apis -> rest do the  logic in that Ts 
Make service for the common some reusable methods where you will just pass the needed arguments.
Thats all!

Answer (score 1):

both variants are bad, because you have to implement business logic into component side. the name service means that you should have logics into the service and no other places. you must have an observer to let component know that the data is ready for using

Imagine that you use service in different placess if you call all the time back to the server you will have many requests that is no so good.

Answer (score 0):

[Service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) is a broad category encompassing any value, function, or feature that an app needs. A service is typically a class with a narrow, well-defined purpose. It should do something specific and do it well.

Angular distinguishes components from services to increase modularity and reusability. By separating a component's view-related functionality from other kinds of processing, you can make your component classes lean and efficient.

Ideally, a component's job is to enable the user experience and nothing more. A component should present properties and methods for data binding, in order to mediate between the view (rendered by the template) and the application logic (which often includes some notion of a model).

A component can delegate certain tasks to services, such as fetching data from the server, validating user input, or logging directly to the console. By defining such processing tasks in an injectable service class, you make those tasks available to any component. You can also make your app more adaptable by injecting different providers of the same kind of service, as appropriate in different circumstances.

Angular doesn't enforce these principles. Angular does help you follow these principles by making it easy to factor your application logic into services and make those services available to components through dependency injection.

A [component](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components) controls a patch of screen called a view. For example, individual components define and control each of the following views from the Tutorial:

The app root with the navigation links.
The list of heroes.
The hero editor.
You define a component's application logic—what it does to support the view—inside a class. The class interacts with the view through an API of properties and methods.

> check the architecture at [angular](https://angular.io/) doc

Comment: Can u pls make it short either i shld follow approach 1 or 2?

Comment: the service is the place where you going to use httpClient handle the token ,show an error related to http error , share data , show an alert ,shared utility , thing going to be common in certain componnets