# Angular: Handle API Error both in interceptor and subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, angular-http-interceptors

I have some APIs that need to handle business logic if the API throws any error. At this point, I use an interceptor to handle the errors for any APIs. This works fine but this does not allow me to call the "error" part in subscribe. Below am specifying a sample snippet for the current scenario:

**interceptor**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((err, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    this.toastr.error(!err.error.message ? 'Internal Server Error' : err.error.message);
                    return of(err as any);
                }
                throw err;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

What I want is the interceptor to work as it is and let me write business logic in the error part of subscribing as below:

**component**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClientService) {}

sampleMethod() {
    this.http.getAllData().subscribe({
        next: response => { ... work on success response },
        error: error => { ... perform specific task required on error scenario } // This is not running until & unless I write logic to skip this certain API in interceptor
    });
}
```

I have shown here using a single API but in my requirement, I have multiple scenarios where I need to write the logic in the error part and I don't want to write much logic in the interceptor.

Can anyone provide me with any example of how to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Apparently it works the same with `throw err` and [`throwError(err)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError).

Comment: Services are a better place for handling business logic, see the first answer in this stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089067/which-is-the-best-place-to-keep-logic-in-angular

Comment: @CharlieV my question is if I make a global interceptor and want to handle logic in error cases I guess my issue will not be solved even if I keep business logic in service

Comment: @Avishek You need to implement GlobalErrorHandler class in angular. If you want then do connect with me by email `grdtechlab@gmail.com` Thanks!

Comment: That is not working because you are returning an `Observable of error`, not `Error` itself. This is used when you dont want subscribe to error out, but instead recieve an empty array in response. You need to either throw or return `httpErrorResponse` if error is of that type, if not just throw or return normal `Error`. But if this is all your interceptor needs to do, i would implemenent custom global ErrorHandler class

Comment: Hey @tony, I have implemented a global error handle. So with this, if I call the "error" state from the ```subscribe``` it gets called. However, I want the error handler to handle the toast messages & if any logic is to be implemented for error scenario I can implement from the error state in ```subscribe```

Comment: I have a project on gh for global error handler, check it out https://github.com/3MR1T00/angular-global-error-handler

This one implements snackbar instead of toast, but you can just remove snackbar and add toast or dialog or whatever it is